# Is every extreme point in a compact convex set contained in a defining supporting hyperplane?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, compactness, convex-geometry, locally-convex-spaces

Let $K \subseteq X$ be a compact convex subset of a locally convex space $X$. Let $k \in K$ be an extreme point.

**Question 1:** Does there exist a supporting hyperplane of $X$ containing $k$?

I *think* the answer is “yes” via some Hahn-Banach argument, although I’m a little confused about this at the moment. But what I really want to know is the following:

**Question 2:** Suppose that $K = \cap_i H_i$ where each $H_i$ is a closed half-space. **EDIT:** Suppose also that for each $i$ the face $K \cap \partial(H_i)$ is not empty. **end EDIT** Then is $k$ contained in the boundary of some $H_i$?

That is, assuming the answer to Question 1 is “yes”, I want to know whether I can guarantee that the supporting hyperplane can be chosen from a list of hyperplanes I already have.

**Notes:**

- I’m aware that the extreme point $k$ doesn’t have to be *exposed* — i.e. it need not be the case that $\{k\} = K \cap Y$ for some supporting hyperplane $Y$. But I want to know whether we have $\{k\} \subseteq K \cap Y$ for some supporting hyperplane $Y$.
- If $K$ is the intersection of a finite number of half-spaces, I’m pretty sure the answer to both questions is *yes*. Even in finite dimensions, I’m not sure about the answer if $K$ is the intersection of infinitely many half-spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to question 2 is: "no" even in $X = \mathbb R$. Indeed,
$$
[0,\infty) = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} [-1/n, \infty)
$$
and the extreme point $0$ is not a boundary point of any $[-1/n, \infty)$.

After the edit, we need at least two dimensions, I guess: Take $X = \mathbb R^2$ and
$$
X = \bigcap_{q \in \mathbb Q \cap [0,2 \pi]} \{ x \in \mathbb  R^2 \mid x_1 \cos(q) + x_2 \sin(q) \le 1\}.
$$
That is, we write the unit circle as a countable intersection of half spaces. Note that the boundary of each half space intersects the unit circle.

Comment: I guess you meant $\cap_{n \in \mathbb N} [-1/n, \infty)$. Thanks! I will think a bit whether I’m just missing some obvious additional condition, and the probably just accept your answer.

Comment: Sorry to be a moving target — I added the additional condition that each $K \cap \partial(H_i)$ be non empty.

Comment: @tcamps: Yes, the minus was missing. I also edited my answer according to your edited question.

Comment: I see, in the second example, the intersection is the unit disk. Any point on the unit circle is an extreme point, and if that point is at an irrational-to-$\pi$ angle, then it is not contained in any of the defining hyperplanes. Thanks again!

Comment: I will probably ask a follow-up question asking for the same conclusion with stronger conditions.